# Question tag is not updated on checks performed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a game in which after the answer check is done, the correct any div changes to BTN-green and if wrong then the choosen option changes to BTN-red and correct one changes to BTN-green.
The code for the same is as below:

JavaScript code:

```
function checkAnswer(id)
{
    if(enable_click)
    {
        enable_click = false;
        var checked_opt = document.getElementById(id).text;
        var res = checked_opt.slice(3); 
        if(id == correct_ans)
        {
            document.getElementById(id).className = "btn-green";//not executed 
            ans += 1;

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(correct_ans).className = "btn-green";//not executed
            document.getElementById(id).className = "btn-red";// not executed

        }

    }
    enable_click = true;// after check this is executed
    queNumber += 1;
    display_quiz(queNumber);
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <div class="row">
            <!-- option1 -->
            <div class="col-md-6" >  
                <a onclick="checkAnswer(id)" class="btn-pink" id="opt_a">Loading...</a>
            </div>
            <!-- option2 -->
            <div class="col-md-6" >
                <a onclick="checkAnswer(id)" class="btn-pink" id="opt_b">Loading...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row btns">
            <!-- option3 -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a onclick="checkAnswer(id)" class="btn-pink"  id="opt_c">Loading...</a>
            </div>
            <!-- option4 -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a  onclick="checkAnswer(id)" class="btn-pink"  id="opt_d">Loading...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Have a look at commented line and you will get a gist what am I trying to convey.

If you require display_quiz then let me know; it basically display the next question after the answer check.

Comment: use `document.getElementById(id).classList.add('btn-green')`

Comment: this is not working.  if i exclude the the queNumber+=1 and display_quiz function then the document tag is working which i have written..plz suggest on this